# Why does Intel Graphics Monitor crash after I set a depth stencil state in my Direct3D 11 application?

Tags: c#, c++, directx11, profiling, intel

I'm programming a managed Direct3D 11 application with SlimDX. I want to use Intel Graphics Monitor to capture draw calls for a single frame. When I try to set a depth stencil state my application crashes...any ideas?

Comment: I recommend asking on StackOverflow, as this is a pretty specific programming problem that's not really game-related.

Comment: You're probably misusing the API in some way. Try turning on the D3D debug layers and fix any errors that reveals.